# The region of allowed values ​​for solving the equation in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

```
In[2]:= Solve[sqrt(2x-9) == sqrt(4x+3), x]

Out[2]= {{x -> -6}}
```

But mathematically there is no solution, since sqrt (-21) is not defined. There is a flag that is responsible for this?

Comment: You can consider asking future Mathematica-related questions on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Mathematica assumes that all variables are complex numbers, and when working in the set of complex numbers, `Sqrt[-21]` is well defined.

You can tell Mathematica (version 8) that you are working on the set of reals using

```
Solve[Sqrt[2 x - 9] == Sqrt[4 x + 3], x, Reals]
```

which gives no solution. For versions earlier than 8, you need to use `Reduce` if you want to specify a domain.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `Reduce` equation while requiring `x` to belong to the `Reals`.  See [the Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EquationsAndInequalitiesOverDomains.html) for an example.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/es8Zq756 Almost the same thing.

Comment: @Ticksy You are using incorrect syntax.  Please look at some examples in the docs.  It's `Sqrt[x]`, not `sqrt(x)`.